# no output when running python file in background

Tags: python, linux, stdout

I wrote a program in python that uses the following code:

```
for item in items:
       sys.stdout.write("".join(str(i) for i in item))
       sys.stdout.write(self.separator)
       sys.stdout.flush()
```

to print out its output.

When I run it normally via the terminal:

```
vm@ubuntu:~$ ./program.py
```

it works well.

Also when I run it and send the stdout to a file:

```
vm@ubuntu:~$ ./program.py > file
```

But when I try to run it in background:

```
vm@ubuntu:~$ ./program.py > file &
```

it doesn't fill the file with output.

Someone know how to solve it?

Comment: How many items are there in `items`?  Seems like a buffering issue.

Comment: To @codeforester's point can you try running python with the -u flag to see if buffering is indeed the culprit? `python -u ./program.py > file &`

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
./program.py > file &
```

Instead of

```
./program.py > file $
```

Comment: I use &.  It is just a typing mistake when I wrote the question.

Comment: Then try giving nohup ./program.py > file &

Comment: Or sudo nohup bash -x program.py > file &

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by removing the line that waiting for KeyboardInterrupt `raw_input()`
and replace it with endless while loop.

First question in order to get better understand: Why this line causes the process not to passes the stdout properly when it runs at background?
This issue doesn't appear when it runs in fg.

Now, I need to kill it by terminate the process

```
kill -9 PID
```

Second question: How can I check for keystrokes via its buffer (like it can be checked in C) without using the blocking and wait function raw_input()?

Answer (score 0):

The whole solution:

1. Redirect the stdin to an empty file
2. Add the following code to the running program:

   while(True):
       try:
           a=raw_input()
           for ai in a:
               if ai == "q":
                   tb.stop()
                   tb.wait()
3. run the program with the following command

   ./program.py < fileSTDIN &
4. In order to terminate the running bg process I only need to write 'q' to the file

   echo "q" > fileSTDIN